# JQuery to show/hide Divs Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server

I am running a SQL query to get dropdown select value. The values are now int.

What I need to do is show the div when Dropdown Value is **"Other"**

So I am using this Jquery code to get the **text** of the dropdown that is selected. Which is working fine.

**[Working Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubrcq/212/)**

```
<select name="hours" id="hours" class="time">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">Other</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#hours').change(function() {
$('#hours_text').val( this.value );
$('#hours_text2').val($('option:selected',this).text());
});
</script>
```

The issue is when I am hiding the div. The **text** is not passing into Jquery. Its only accepting the option value. I need it to accept the **text** value which is **"Other"** not **05**

Before the values were varchar so this was not an issue before.

Here is the code for hiding and showing Div.(not working) [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubrcq/213/)

```
$('#hours').change(function () {
$('#hours_text').val($('option:selected', this).text());
$('.showotherpDescription').hide();
$('#' + $(this).val()).show.text();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#hours').change(function () {
    $('#hours_text').val($('option:selected', this).text());
    $('.showotherpDescription').hide();
    $('#' + $('option:selected', this).text()).show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ubrcq/215/)**

Comment: Aha  $('#' + $('option:selected', this).text()).show(); that did the trick. Thanks working .

Answer (score 0):

the property for checking the text contained by the option would be .html() not .val()

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this:

```
$('#hours').change(function () {
  var sel = $('option:selected', this).text();
  if (sel == "Other") {
    $('.showotherpDescription').show();
  } else {
    $('.showotherpDescription').hide();
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should do the trick. I added some console output so you can see what and why:

```
$('#hours').change(function () {
    $('#hours_text').val($('option:selected', this).text());
    $('.showotherpDescription').hide();
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log(this.selectedIndex);
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
    $('#' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML).show();
});
```